# Array Converts in typescript,javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, converters

I have some problem in creating the required form of an array. I want to delete the key named **service_id** and put their data into the outside.

```
 "restaurant_services": Array[2][
            {
              "service_id": {
                "added_on": "2018-07-07T07:56:35.054Z",
                "deleted": false,
                "_id": "5b4072332c94ca607ffcf65b",
                "service_name": "Cafe",
                "service_status": 1,
                "__v": 0
              },
              "_id": "5b433cd7e066e6623b9c9ce6"
            },
            {
              "service_id": {
                "added_on": "2018-07-07T10:01:05.083Z",
                "deleted": false,
                "_id": "5b408f61caeca976851923c4",
                "service_name": "Dine In",
                "service_status": 1,
                "__v": 0
              },
              "_id": "5b433cd7e066e6623b9c9ce5"
            }
    ],
```

i would like to convert the above array to below.

```
"restaurant_services": Array[2][
        {
            "added_on": "2018-07-07T07:56:35.054Z",
            "deleted": false,
            "_id": "5b4072332c94ca607ffcf65b",
            "service_name": "Cafe",
            "service_status": 1,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "added_on": "2018-07-07T10:01:05.083Z",
            "deleted": false,
            "_id": "5b408f61caeca976851923c4",
            "service_name": "Dine In",
            "service_status": 1,
            "__v": 0
        }
],
```

Any Suggestion For that to covert this type of array?

Comment: you can use `arr.map(({service_id})=>service_id)`

Comment: It looks like your are using MongoDB. Are you looking for the [`$replaceRoot` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to remove the `service_id`. Here is the snippet below.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
const restaurant_services = [
  {
    "service_id": {
      "added_on": "2018-07-07T07:56:35.054Z",
      "deleted": false,
      "_id": "5b4072332c94ca607ffcf65b",
      "service_name": "Cafe",
      "service_status": 1,
      "__v": 0
    },
    "_id": "5b433cd7e066e6623b9c9ce6"
  },
  {
    "service_id": {
      "added_on": "2018-07-07T10:01:05.083Z",
      "deleted": false,
      "_id": "5b408f61caeca976851923c4",
      "service_name": "Dine In",
      "service_status": 1,
      "__v": 0
    },
    "_id": "5b433cd7e066e6623b9c9ce5"
  }
]

const restaurant_services_updated = restaurant_services.map(service => service.service_id);

console.log(restaurant_services_updated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.prototype.map()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

In your case

```
var originalArr  = [
        {
          "service_id": {
            "added_on": "2018-07-07T07:56:35.054Z",
            "deleted": false,
            "_id": "5b4072332c94ca607ffcf65b",
            "service_name": "Cafe",
            "service_status": 1,
            "__v": 0
          },
          "_id": "5b433cd7e066e6623b9c9ce6"
        },
        {
          "service_id": {
            "added_on": "2018-07-07T10:01:05.083Z",
            "deleted": false,
            "_id": "5b408f61caeca976851923c4",
            "service_name": "Dine In",
            "service_status": 1,
            "__v": 0
          },
          "_id": "5b433cd7e066e6623b9c9ce5"
        }
]

var  newArr = arr.map(function(currValue){


 return currValue.service_id
 })

console.log('desired result',newArr)
```